Flutter dependency issue in "image_picker" and "tflite"
I am facing problem while adding the depency files like "tflite" and "image_picker" in pubspec.yaml. IDE is android studio.
Actually a image and later camera mobile app is required which uses custom tensorflow lite model incorporation. Help is needed in this regard could be any form like book, learning path or problem solution.
When only "tflite_flutter" is added instead of "tflite" then project successfully builds.  While searching online, it reveals that there is compatibility issue. Changing the JDK from 17 to 11, code amendments in androidmanifest.xml and build.gradle files none of them solved the problem.
The problem that appears is below
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process D:\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\ahmed.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Where flutter pub outdated commands shows below results
direct dependencies: all up-to-date.
dev_dependencies: all up-to-date.
transitive dependencies:
transitive dev_dependencies:
all dependencies are up-to-date.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

minimum supported SDK version to Flutter 3.19/Dart 3.3.

The problem is solved by adding the below statement in "gradle.properties" file located in [App_name] > android > gradle.properties
The statement that is added,
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17.0.x
The right side of equal sign is the location of JDK. Change the location accordingly. Thanks
